# JAX-WS client | Sending client requests with security header

Tags: web-services, spring-security, spring-ws

I have implemented a Spring WS using XWSS for security. I have added a security configuration policy file into my application.

```
<xwss:SecurityConfiguration xmlns:xwss="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/xwss/config"
    dumpMessages="true">    
    <xwss:RequireTimestamp 
        id="tsp" 
        maxClockSkew="60" 
        timestampFreshnessLimit="300">
    </xwss:RequireTimestamp>
    <xwss:RequireUsernameToken 
        id="token" 
        passwordDigestRequired="false" 
        nonceRequired="false"/>
    <xwss:Timestamp></xwss:Timestamp>
    <xwss:UsernameToken 
        name="service" 
        password="service" 
        id="uToken" 
        digestPassword="true"
        useNonce="true"/>
</xwss:SecurityConfiguration>
```

Now I am developing a client to access the WS. The security works fine. But I am unable to test the SUCCESS case in which the client can successfully get a response from my service. The problem is I don't know how to make my client send the usernametoken and timestamp along with the request. I am using NetBeans IDE and I am implementing a JAX-WS client to access the Spring WS using [this tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html).

Please let me know what needs to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Spring WSS there is not much difference between adding a security header to the ingoing soap messages or to the outgoing ones. The process is very similar.

In both cases, you should create a interceptor for adding the security header. It is described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html#security-wss4j-security-interceptor). So, if you create the WS client using Spring you should not have problems, especially if you have already developed the server side, but the tutorial you referenced doesn't look like using Spring for implementing the client.

Comment: Also, you can use SoapUI to test your Web service.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding the following code in you client class / class extending the webservicetgatewaysupport.

```
SoapHeader header = msg.getSoapHeader();
StringSource headerSource = new StringSource("<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-
open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\" mustUnderstand=\"1\">   <wsse:UsernameToken> 
<wsse:Username>"+userName+"</wsse:Username>  <wsse:Password Type=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/
oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText\">"+password+"</wsse:Password> </wsse:UsernameToken>" 
+"</wsse:Security>");
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.transform(headerSource, header.getResult());
```

The above has to go in the message call back handler of the marshalSendANDRecieve metho of the webserviceTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Check this [sample](https://github.com/gregturn/learning-spring-ws/tree/security/learning-spring-ws-server/src/main/resources) for client.

And you could use SoapUI to test your server. Import WSDL, then select any request and open "Properties" window in left-bottom corner. You would see "Username", "Password" and "WSS-Password Type" related settings.